# Show/Hide Div in jQuery, issue with "skipping" divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have made a jQuery script in which you can hide or show one of divs (first one) on click of button `hide`

The code looks like this in script:

```
$('.hideButton').click( function() {
    var toggleWidth = $(".first").width() == 100 ? "10px" : "100px";
    $('.first').animate({ width: toggleWidth},200);

    if ( $('.first').width() == 10 ){
        $(".content").attr("hidden",false);
    }
    else if ( $('.first').width() == 100 ){
        $(".content").attr("hidden",true);
    }

});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="contain">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="navigation">
                navigation
            </div>
            <div class="advert">
                advert
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="main">
            main
            <br/>
            <button class="hideButton">hide</button>
            <br/>
            <div class="first">
                1
            </div>
            <div class="second">
                2
            </div>
            <div class="third">
                3
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.row{
   margin-left:0px;
}
.navigation{
    height:100px;
    background-color:orange;
    width:400px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.advert{
    height:100px;
    background-color:lime;
    width:200px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.main{
    width:600px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: magenta;
}
.first{
   width:100px;
    height:80%;
   background-color: yellow;
   display:inline-block;
}
.second{
   width:100px;
   height:80%;
   background-color: blue;
    display:inline-block;
}
.third{
   width:100px;
    height:80%;
   background-color: red;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

And best way is that you see it in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dzorz/EhjeA/

Now I have a issue with other two divs. When I click the hide button and first div gets animated, other two divs on animation, both skip to the end of first div and when the animation is done they get back in place.. It is really annoying and I don't know how to solve it...

I just need that one div that gets hidden on click of button and that he does not affect anything else...

Is this example fixable or maybe you could suggest me some nice jQuery plugin that does the same?

Comment: One lame way to fix it is to make .main div positioned relatively and the first, second, and third position absolutely with specified left coordinates.

Comment: Would you like something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/EhjeA/4/) (Note: This is an altogether different approach. Posting just in case you are looking at other options)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of displaying these 3 as `inline-block`, remove the display and float them left instead using `float: left` in your CSS.

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EhjeA/2/)

```
.first{
   width:100px;
   height:80%;
   background-color: yellow;
   float: left;
}
.second{
   width:100px;
   height:80%;
   background-color: blue;
   float: left;
}
.third{
   width:100px;
   height:80%;
   background-color: red;
   float: left;
}
```

Comment: Love your answer but maybe I need those inline-block property, will test this asnswer on my actual project now

Comment: With `float: left` you can actually keep `inline-block` in your CSS as well and it still fixes your problem. http://jsfiddle.net/EhjeA/5/ I just don't see you needing it with left float, but you can keep it in there just in case.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your CSS:

```
.first,.second,.third {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

During the animation, the `overflow` is set to `overflow: hidden` which causes the other inline elements to shift down. Adding the `vertical-align: top` should fix the issue.

**Updated fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/EhjeA/3/

Comment: Love your answer, will test it now

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the offending divs in a wrapper with a fixed width: http://jsfiddle.net/EhjeA/1/

```
.wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
}

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="first">
    1
  </div>
</div>
```